# MS-EXCEL How to Rank three columns together using countif

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I am trying to rank these three columns based on the minimum values in all three simultaneously, using the formula shown in the picture. But somehow, it selects the values that aren't minimum in one of the columns, as i highlighted in Yellow.
How do I organize the formula so it wont give the rank this way. Ideally it should have ignore the 58 161 41 value.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: I agree with the answer below. Refill from `D2`. Your results are all wrong. If you've done that in the image shown, show us the formula in `D5` and `D26`.

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

Therefore I conclude there is a fill error in your sheet. This has meant that the problem row does not contain the formula you think it does.

Reapplying the fill down from the cell you have shown in your screenshot should resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you but have checked it several times and the formula is the same in the entire column.

Answer (score 0):

As you have ruled out the possibility of an incorrect formula in that row (fill error), there is no way this can normally happen.

Therefore we must conclude your Excel workbook has become corrupted.

Excel detects some types of corruption itself, when it will automatically start the File Recovery mode. In other cases, you must start the recovery process manually

Microsoft provide these instructions to manually [repair a corrupted workbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-a-corrupted-workbook-153a45f4-6cab-44b1-93ca-801ddcd4ea53).